# Deleting multiple file and its name variants with PHP from a text file list

Tags: php

I need to create a script to delete a bunch of images in a wordpress directory. As you may already know, a single image file can have multiple variants, depending on how the images are rendered.

Anyway, i have a list of images in a text file, which contains the following:

```
wp-content/uploads/2018/09/L_14BQ-FK1
wp-content/uploads/2018/09/L_15EKP160VIBROBT-KIT
wp-content/uploads/2018/09/L_29DS15172GB
wp-content/uploads/2018/09/L_29DS18172GB
wp-content/uploads/2018/09/L_29DS2415
```

For example i need to delete L_14BQ-FK1.jpg and its variants such as L_14BQ-FK1-100x100.jpg, L_14BQ-FK1-200x200.jpg, etc.

So far i have tried the foreach inside a foreach but its not working:

```
$list = file('list.txt');
if ($list === false) {
    die('Cannot open file');
}

foreach($list as $file){
$theFile = glob($file.'*.jpg');  

   foreach ($theFile as $single){
     echo $single."<br>";
   }
}
```

Surprisingly the echo only produced the last list and its variants, L_29DS2415-100x100.jpg, L_29DS2415-100x200.jpg, etc

Can someone help please?

Comment: It should work. You have verified that this particular directory actually has the variant files? Do a var_dump on the file list and ensure it's clean, e.g. no newlines included in the filename (use FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES).

Comment: @MarkusAO lol, you just gave the explanation of why it did _not_ work, together with “it should work”.

Comment: Right, it does say in the manual that the newline is still attached by default. So it *shouldn't* work as is, however with the flag in place (or a `trim` in the loop), the code above should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, it does help reading the manual :) I'll revise the code in the answer below, tested and working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Reading at the file manual at php.net, I just realised that the array returned from the function FILE include the new line, so revising my original code by adding the flags of 'FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES' works perfectly.

So the final code will be:

```
$list = file('list.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
if ($list === false) {
    die('Cannot open file');
}

foreach($list as $file){
$theFile = glob($file.'*.jpg');  

   foreach ($theFile as $single){
     echo $single."<br>";
   }
}
```